# Deserialization Error: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I was able to serialize shapes as an object and load it again or redraw it again into a picturebox. The problem now is that I can serialize the image into Base64String but I can't deserialize it into Image again and redraw in the PictureBox. Any suggestions?

> I provided my code on Serialization and Deserialization. I excluded the one that draws the shapes again as it is irrelevant to the question.

**Serialization Method**

```
public void Serialization()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Layers>)); //Serializer
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();           //Creates and Opens a SaveFileDialog
            save.Filter = "Seal Creator File (*.sealFile)|*.sealFile";     //Creates a filter fir saving the Project File
            save.DefaultExt = ".seal";
            save.AddExtension = true;

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Serialization process for the Class
                FileStream file = File.Create(save.FileName);
                ser.Serialize(file, draw.layers);
                file.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved"); //Saving Confirmation
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Catching the Error
            String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
            Debug.WriteLine(innerMessage);
        }
    }
```

**Deserialization**

```
public void Deserialize(StreamReader file)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Layers> _layers = new List<Layers>();      
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Layers>));   
            _layers = (List<Layers>)ser.Deserialize(file);   //Here's where the program catches an error. 
        }
    }
```

**This is how I serialized and Deserialize an image in the Layer Class**

```
 [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("ImageData")]
    public String ImageData
    {
        get
        {
            //Serialize
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //Deserialize
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
              imageBytes.Length);

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            this.image = (Bitmap)image;
        }
    }
```

> Error: Parameter is not valid.

**Edit**

> Layer Class

```
    public enum Type
    {
       Rectangle, Square, Circle, Ellipse, Triangle, Image
    }
    public Layers.Type type { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
    public PointF location { get; set;}
    public int radius { get; set; }
    public int strokeThickness { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public Bitmap image { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ImageData")]
    public String ImageData
    {
        get
        {
            //Serialize
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //Deserialize
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
              imageBytes.Length);

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            this.image = (Bitmap)image;
        }
    }
    public RectangleF rect { get; set; }
    public PointF centerSerializable
    {
        get { return Shape.center; }
        set { Shape.center = value; }
    }

    public Layers(Layers.Type image, RectangleF rect, Bitmap bm)
    {
        this.type = image;
        this.rect = rect;
        this.image = bm;
    }
    public Layers (Layers.Type shape, float width, float height, int radius, int strokeThickness, Color color, PointF location)
    {
        this.type = shape;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.strokeThickness = strokeThickness;
        this.color = color;
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Layers()
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try to `file.ReadToEnd()` before deserializing?

Comment: And there is no other parameters in Layers class that can raise an error? Are you 100% sure that ImageData causing the issue?

Comment: @Reniuz yes, because what my Xml have right now is only the image data. I did not include shapes in order to test the image serialization individually.

Comment: @PaulKaram not yet.

Comment: @PaulKaram now it's showing Root element is missing.

Comment: Could it be that the file is not well written in first place? Have you checked your XML? I am not sure that this could happen... but worth a check.

Comment: Show us your Layers class

Comment: Ok I tried your code and it works. It is NOT related to ImageData, serializer and deserialize code parts. My blind shot - you passing wrong file to deserializer. Make sure you passing the StreamReader of your serialized xml file.

Comment: @Reniuz added Layer Class. Still doesn' work for me. How did you use my code?

Comment: Posted working code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nAnawr

Comment: I am still pretty sure you passing wrong file. That's why it missing root element.

Comment: A well formed xml file cannot have a list at the root level.  You are trying to deserialize a List : typeof(List<Layers>).  You either have to add a element above the List, or use XmlReader and use the option : ConformanceLevel.Fragment

Comment: @jdweng It will be wrapped with <ArrayOfLayers> root tag

Comment: @Renuiz : Don't assume anything!!! How can we tell that it is wrapped in another tag?  Will serialization work with a list at the root level?